Moving coins from legacy wallet to new wallet
I need some help moving my coins from legacy wallet to new wallet. Here is original transaction
https://explorer.iota.org/legacy-mainnet/address/OLQHDSSDNRLGKEXJQSOFVWIK9TBOEZLRGHAIQ9SFIP9YVFUGQTMHOYSNGQXTKOVTXZONBKRWHH9JYRMXX
original public key: OLQHDSSDNRLGKEXJQSOFVWIK9TBOEZLRGHAIQ9SFIP9YVFUGQTMHOYSNGQXTKOVTXZONBKRWHH9JYRMXXBWTDZTR9X
seems like some global snapshot happened which moved my coins. I need to get them back to my new iota wallet.
Discord community suggested to reach out to iota foundation. I have sent two emails to iota foundation but there is no reply.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
